# Center div with position absolute?

Tags: css

I was wondering how I could center this div.

https://jsfiddle.net/eLjy45zq/

I tried adding auto margin but it won't center it on the screen.. i also want it to be responsive. i didn't want to add a fixed width because i want the border top/bottom line to match the length of the word. Also, is there a way i can make the top and bottom lines double?

```
   .name {
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 80px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: A better solution may present itself given a bit more context. Where does this appear on the page? Why does it need to be `position:absolute`? What is the bigger picture of what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.name {
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 80px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;       
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eLjy45zq/2/

Create a wrapper and use `display: inline-block;` to get the lines to work how you want them.

(Added position: fixed to the wrapper, change as needed)

Comment: but the border line spans the whole screen, whereas I want it to match the length of the text